# Ubuntu (LiveUSB, not hard install) "suddenly" won't boot from USB stick after Windows XP format

Tags: boot

I formatted because the Windows XP I was using wouldn't let me view the drive in the window without formatting first, so I just said what the heck.

Turns out, after using the Linux USB creator, placing the ISO on disc properly and booting, BIOS hangs; no bootloader, no startup, nothing.

Windows XP's formatting screwed something up with my USB's filesystem, and I'm uncertain of what to do.

Help?! My business depends on me using an OS, so prompt ideas are a must and very appreciated(no money).

Comment: possible duplicate of [My Ubuntu LiveUSB won't boot after formatting it on Windows XP. HELP!](http://askubuntu.com/questions/228102/my-ubuntu-liveusb-wont-boot-after-formatting-it-on-windows-xp-help)

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting the USB stick with ubuntu's "disk utility". Then create a bootable again using start-up-disk-creator or universal USB installer.

Comment: How can I format it on Ubuntu if I can't boot Ubuntu up in the first place?