# My Ubuntu LiveUSB won't boot after formatting it on Windows XP. HELP!

Tags: boot

I formatted because the Windows XP I was using wouldn't let me view the drive in the window without formatting first, so I just said what the heck.

Turns out, after using the Linux USB creator, placing the ISO on disc properly and booting, BIOS hangs; no bootloader, no startup, nothing.

Windows XP's formatting screwed something up with my USB's filesystem, and I'm uncertain of what to do.

Help?! My business depends on me using an OS, so prompt ideas are a must and very appreciated(no money).

PS: I checked the contents of the disc, and they are all okay.

STEPS:

1.Formatted the USB because Windows XP said I couldn't access the drive contents without formatting it first. I initially only took this step because I changed the a setting mistakenly on Ubuntu's system settings that resulted in the drive being unable to boot. This resulted in my 16GB flash drive shrinking to 2GB.

2.Used Linux USB PenDrive creator program, selected appropriate drive letter, selected appropriate Ubuntu 12.04 ISO 32-bit file, and waited until finished.

3.Unmounted USB drive, plugged into my computer, BIOS already configured to boot from USB, not hard drives containing any other OS, and BIOS just shows the stupid flickering input character in 80x25 text video mode.

Comment: Please edit your comment with the order of the steps you took.

Comment: I just did, and left where I'm stuck at.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to any working PC, you could just get yourself another working live CD/flash drive again. This might considering all things the easiest route for you.

Also I am not quite exactly sure what it is you did. Could it have been that your bootloader was on your flash drive and you formatted that?

Comment: What other "working PC" would this be? The only one I have access to is the same Windows XP, and after formatting my 16GB drive shrunk to 2GB now and can't boot ubuntu after using the Linux USB creator program afterwards.

Comment: So you Windows is still booting?


What you can try:
1) Re-format your flash drive again and re-installing Ubuntu with the Linux USB PenDrive creator.
2) You could alternatively also  try [LiLi](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download) or [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to install Ubuntu.
3) If that fails too, you could have a look at appropriate [Ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) and try the alternative methods of installing Ubuntu.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll have no other options ... let's see what goes.

Comment: I tried what you said, and the drive is still 2GB, Ubuntu won't boot (must be a problem regarding the bootloader, the formatting, or the MBR).